# How to get rid of flicker

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, charts

```
namespace stock4
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.SetStyle(ControlStyles.ResizeRedraw, true);
            this.chart1.AxisViewChanged += chart1_AxisViewChanged;
            this.chart1.MouseMove += new System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventHandler(this.chart1_MouseMove);
        }

        private void CandleStick_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            CHART();
        }

        string path = @"C:\Users\1\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\stock3\stock3\bin\Debug\#S-PG1440.csv";
        static int count = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\Users\1\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\stock3\stock3\bin\Debug\#S-PG1440.csv").Length;
        int[] index = new int[count];
        DateTime[] nums = new DateTime[count];
        double[,] mass = new double[count, 4];
        public void CHART()
        {   
        //Here the data from the file is read and entered into the array.
        //chart1.Series["price"].Points.AddXY(index[i], mass[i, 1], mass[i, 2], mass[i, 0], mass[i, 3]);
        }

        private void chart1_AxisViewChanged(object sender, ViewEventArgs e)
        {
         //Autoscaling the graph
        }

        public static string str;

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Form newForm = new Form();
            newForm.DoubleBuffered = true;//Error   1 Cannot access 
            //protected member 'System.Windows.Forms.Control.DoubleBuffered' 
            //via a qualifier of type 'System.Windows.Forms.Form';
            //the qualifier must be of type 'stock4.Form1' 
            //(or derived from it)  
            newForm.Show();
            newForm.Width = 150;
            newForm.Height = 230;
            newForm.BackColor = Color.White;
            newForm.Paint += new PaintEventHandler(MyPaintHandler);
        }

        private void chart1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            chart1.ChartAreas[0].CursorX.SetCursorPixelPosition(e.Location, false);
            chart1.ChartAreas[0].CursorY.SetCursorPixelPosition(e.Location, false);
            int val = (int)chart1.ChartAreas[0].CursorX.Position;
            if (val >= 0)
            {
                double current = chart1.ChartAreas[0].CursorY.Position;
                str = "time: " + nums[val] + "\n" +
                    "current: " + current + "\n" +
                    "open:    " + mass[val, 0] + "\n" +
                    "high: "    + mass[val, 1] + "\n" +
                    "low: "     + mass[val, 2] + "\n" +
                    "close: "   + mass[val, 3];
            }
        }

        static void MyPaintHandler(object objSender, PaintEventArgs pea)
        {
            Form newForm = (Form)objSender;
            Graphics grfx = pea.Graphics;
            grfx.DrawString(str, newForm.Font, Brushes.Black, 0, 0);
            newForm.Invalidate();
            Thread.Sleep(1);
        }
    }
}
```

I read the data from the form and pass it to another for display.
I create a form to display when a button event occurs(button1_Click).
Data for "str" is taken from another form.

Perhaps the second form is not needed?
I need a separate window from the main form to display the data.
UPDATED THE CODE! Part of the code is not on the subject was removed from the comments.

How do I place the string " newForm.DoubleBuffered = true " in "button1_Click" without errors? It is possible a code sample?

[image]

Comment: newform.Refresh() causes a repaint. Try removing that.

Comment: Without it, the data is not updated when the mouse moves.

Comment: If you want the MouseMove to update something let it do it. Don't  do it in the Paint event! What flickers? The Form? Did you turn on its doublebuffering??

Comment: You could try using newform.Invalidate instead. Currently when the repaint happens it's triggering a further repaint so it just redraws itself twice. As TaW said, you probably should trigger the paint in MouseMove.

Comment: You need to invalidate whatever needs repainting in your `MouseMoved` handler; do not draw in your `MouseMoved` handler or call `Refresh` or `Sleep` in your `Paint` handler.

Comment: To display the data you could us anything, maybe a label will do. You don't explain your goals well enough to advise..

Comment: You need to get a book or follow a tutorial. WinForms graphics is too complicated to learn through trial and error.

Comment: Well, as we said: Flicker (or worse) will always occur if you trigger a repaint/refresh in a paint event. Did you do as I told you?

Comment: Added a message picture.
Tried double buffering, didn't help.

Comment: Also: I would probably not use an extra  form but simply add a ToolTip to the chart.

Comment: The tooltip is uninformative.
In MouseMove, I only get a row of data and I don't draw anything in it.
If I understand you correctly: the code of "MyPaintHandler", move "chart1_MouseMove"?

Comment: Replaced by "newForm.Invalidate();"
Flickers less, but would still it there is.
Can be example code, so as experience I have little.

Comment: You don't really need the text to be modified in "MouseMove", as that event can be triggered too frequent. You might use a timer instead, to periodically query the cursor location, with a smaller frequency, which can reduce flickers.

Comment: The shape flicker occurs when the mouse is stationary.

Comment: Updated the code. Posted the entire.

Comment: How do I place the string " newForm.DoubleBuffered = true " in "button1_Click" without errors?
It is possible a code sample?

Comment: You've got numerous problems with this. You need to rethink what you need to do. But to resolve flicker, what you should be doing is Creating a bitmap, doing your drawing and updating to that bitmap, then drawing that bitmap onto your main `Graphics` object. This will remove flicker from Winforms.

Comment: @Ice: He want to display a piece of text and update it during mousemove. No need to paint anything let alone create a bitmap!

Comment: Tried to inherit " Form1":
Form1 newForm = new Form1();
newForm.DoubleBuffered = true;
The shape does not flicker, but has dragged the entire graph from " Form1". And the error does not occur, but it turns out some " ugliness"

Comment: You were right about DoubleBuffered being only accessble in the class, not for its instances. But, as I said you do not need it anyway.  I'll post an example..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Forget about painting, doublebuffering etc.

Simply add a [`Label`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.label?view=netframework-4.7.2) control to the 2nd form and access it in the chart's  `MouseMove` event!

Make  `newForm`  a class level variable:

```
Form newForm = null;
```

In your button click write something like this:

```
newForm = new Form();
..
Label lbl = new Label() { Name = "myLabel", Parent = newForm };
newForm.Show();
```

In your `MouseMove` write something like this:

```
if (newForm != null && newForm.Controls.ContainsKey("myLabel"))
   ((Label)newForm.Controls["myLabel"]).Text = str;
```

Very simple, no flicker and you are free to style the `Label` in any way you like.

[image]

Comment: In" button1_Click "added the line" Label lbl = new Label () { Name = "myLabel", Parent = newForm };"
In" chart1_MouseMove "added" if (newForm != null & & newForm.Controls.ContainsKey ("myLabel"))
 
((Label)newForm.Controls ["myLabel"]).Text = str;"
Three identical errors are written: Error 1 The name 'newForm' does not exist in the current context.    The "MyPaintHandler" function was removed and the handler for this event was removed.

Comment: That's right, sorry I forgot a line.. Updated.

Comment: The form is updated and does not flicker.
But prints only the first line "time".
Not showing the rest of "current", "open", "high", "low", "close".
Can't you tell me why?

Comment: Understood- " lbl.AutoSize = true;"

Comment: TaW, thank you very much!

Comment: No problem. Glad you got what you want..